# Trait needs to be imported in current scope even though object module implement the trait

Tags: rust

I want a character one at a time from `BytesMut` object. For this purpose, I used the `get_u8()` from the [bytes::Buf](https://docs.rs/bytes/latest/src/bytes/buf/buf_impl.rs.html#287) trait.

Since, `BytesMut` [implements](https://docs.rs/bytes/latest/src/bytes/bytes_mut.rs.html#1043) `bytes::Buf`, I was hoping that I could directly call `get_u8` on `BytesMut` object without having to import `use bytes::Buf` trait in the file where I am calling `get_u8()` on the `BytesMut` object.

The error that I get is:

```
no method named `get_u8` found for struct `BytesMut` in the current scope
items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope.
```

I get the error and am aware that I have to import the trait in the current file with `use bytes::Buf`. What I am not sure about is the rationale behind this implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rust traits do not have to be implemented *inside* the structure's own `impl`. A trait can, generally speaking, be implemented in the crate that defines either the structure or the trait (the exact rules are a bit more complicated because of the presence of blanket `impl`s, reference types, and multi-parameter traits). So if you call `foo.bar` on `foo` of type `Foo`, then that could actually be the `bar` method on `trait Bar` which is in some crate in the middle of nowhere that isn't at all related to the crate that defined `Foo`.

Rust can't search every possible crate installed on your machine for the method. That would slow compilation down to a crawl and also create some very confusing error messages. Instead, Rust requires that the trait method be in-scope at the time of the call.

```rust
// foo.rs (in crate my_foo)
pub struct Foo;

// bar.rs (in crate my_bar)
pub trait Bar {
  fn bar(&self);
}

impl Bar for Foo {
  fn bar(&self) {
    println!("Hello :)");
  }
}
```

In this case, the implementation `impl Bar for Foo` is not in the same file (or even the same crate) as `Foo` itself, so unless Rust requires that you have the trait method in-scope, it would have no idea what `bar` is, *even* if `Foo` is in-scope.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @silvio. It cleared things for me.